# Verify signature from set of public keys, but not revel which specific key it was

Tags: public-key

Does a system exist where it is possible to verify a signature is from a public key in a specific set of public keys, but also not know which key it was?

The idea being you know a member of a group signed the message without reveling who it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature

$\color{white}{I needed twenty-five more characters.}$

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are looking for, [group signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_signature) may also be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Group signatures and ring signatures are of course good answers but note that if you don't want traceability or linkability you can just give everybody the same key.